# How to align an iframe?

Tags: html, iframe

I'm having an iframe that shows only a section of a website (position: absolute). Notice that the iframe is at the very top of my page.
[image]
Now I want to align that particular iframe to be under a heading, so there should be some space from the top, like this.
[image: Example]
I can't figure out how. I've tried using `position: relative` in `<div>`, didn't work. I've tried using `padding-top` or `top` in `<div>` but the section shown in the iframe will move also. How to make the iframe acts like a normal element (so that it responds to the `<br>` tags, or make it positioned at a particular section of the page?

```
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><be>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <div style="align: center; position: static; width: 100%">
    <iframe src="https://www.liveworksheets.com/ik1904958nl"
      style="position: absolute; top: -620px; left: 250px; width: 66%; height: 2230px" scrolling="no"></iframe>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

there are several to do what you want (if I understand well!)
snippet here is "old" way with a container and relative absolute position.
could be also be with a grid, more modern way

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.heading {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
}

.ifr {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  width: 66%;
  left: 17%;
}

.ifr iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2230px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="heading">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="ifr">
    <iframe src="https://www.liveworksheets.com/ik1904958nl" scrolling="no"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried it and the section shown in the iframe will move also, I think it is because of the `top` thing. From how I understand it, the `top` value will first move the iframe content according to the top of the source page, then it moves the iframe itself according to the top of my page.

Comment: you want no overflow on page and overflow in the iframe?

Comment: There should be no overflow at all. In essence, I want to iframe a section of page A, and place that iframe at a particular position in page B. But as you can see running the code snippet, the `top` property will apply to page A (iframed page), then apply to page B.